# How to read all memory from damaged CF?

Tags: usb, memory, flash, programmer, read

My CF card has been corrupted. I don't know how is that happened. I just using new card (five months old) on `EOS 5D Mark II` with installed `Magic Lantern`. The card just not see as USB device on my PC. And DSLR not launches with this card.

Very possible the controller was damaged, but I not sure. Memory can be damaged too?

In restore service they told me the there are read errors while trying reading via USB (low-level reading) (and requested much money :D)

I want to get info from this manually. How is that possible? (Using hardware programmer device? Another controller? I need more info)

[image]

Comment: Even if you can get the raw data off the chip you can't be certain of how the controller had arranged it.

Comment: Also, that right chip looks very unhealthy, and I would be surprised if you could get very much off it at all.

Comment: I think you need to go to your back-up...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams whats wrong with right chip? Just erased marking...

Comment: That's not erased, that's burned off.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it's very possible I can get info only from left chip? And data can be separately fragmented on two chips - the photos will be fragmented too? Finally the all useful data may be lost due to this? But if the file system has been formatted before using, the big chance left chip has useful data?

Comment: If there is a chance the controller itself is the problem you could try sacrificing an **identical** CF card by moving the memory chips from the duff card to the good one. This wouldn't cost much to have a tech do, even if you don't have the tools yourself (try a cell phone repair guy- they can work magic). But if the memory chip is really overheated I think you're out of luck. Before that (and after you've ruled out all other options) - if the right memory chip is burned try just removing it and see if anything reads.

Comment: If you really want the data, find a data recovery service that deals in CF cards